# MAPI: How to set the default address book directly to account

Tags: outlook, mapi

I've wrote ab-provider, added it to custom message service(consists of ab, store and transport providers) and it works fine - outlook display ab hierarchy and its content.

My question is how to set the default address book directly to account (not for mapi profile)?

For example when user opens address book of exchange account outlook show the GAL container of selected account in outlook.

I assume that each exchange account have it's appropriate default ab-container(GAL). Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIAK the AB provider is linked to the store provider, but that is Exchanger specific. The best you can do is this: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/stephen_griffin/2010/09/13/you-chosewisely/